# Dummit and Foote as a First Text in Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm wondering how Dummit and Foote (3rd ed.) would fair as a first text in Abstract Algebra. I've researched this question  on this site, and found a few opinions, which conflicted. Some people said it is better as a reference text, or something to read after one has a fair deal of exposure to the main ideas of abstract algebra, while others have said it is fine for a beginner. Is a text such as Herstein's *Topics in Algebra*, Artin's *Algebra*, or Fraleigh's *A First Course in Algebra* a better choice?

Here's a summary of the parts of my mathematical background that I presume are relevant. I've covered most of Spivak's famed *Calculus* text (in particular the section on fields, constructing $\mathbf{R}$ from $\mathbf{Q}$, and showing the uniqueness of $\mathbf{R}$ which is probably the most relevant to abstract algebra) so I am totally comfortable with rigorous proofs. I also have a solid knowledge of elementary number theory; the parts that I guess are most relevant to abstract algebra are that I have done some work with modular arithmetic (up to proving fundamental results like Euler's Theorem and the Law of Quadratic Reciprocity), the multiplicative group $(\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z})^{\times}$ (e.g. which ones are cyclic), polynomial rings such as $\mathbf{Z}[x],$ and studying the division algorithm and unique factorization in $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ (for $d \in \mathbf{Z}$). I have only a little bit of experience with linear algebra (about the first 30 pages or so of Halmos' *Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces* and a little bit of computational knowledge with matrices) though.

With this said, I don't have much exposure to actual abstract algebra. I know what a group, ring, field, and vector space are but I haven't worked much with these structures (i.e. I can give a definition, but I have little intuition and only small lists of examples). I have no doubt that Dummit and Foote is comprehensive enough for my purposes (I hope to use it mostly for the sections on group theory, ring theory, and Galois Theory), but is it a good text for building intuition and lists of examples in abstract algebra for someone who has basically none of this? Will I, more than just learning theorems and basic techniques, develop a more abstract and intuitive *understanding* of the fundamental structures (groups, rings, modules, etc.)? It is a very large and supposedly dense text, so will the grand "picture" of group theory, for example, be lost? I've heard it is a book for people who have some basic intuition in group and ring theory, and I hesitate to put myself in this category given my description of my relevant knowledge in the paragraph above. Do you think the text is right for me, or would I be more successful with one of the three texts I mentioned in the first paragraph?

Thanks for reading this (lengthy) question. I look forward to your advice!

Comment: Dummit and Foot is a very good introductory textbook. I started with it and would recommend it to anybody who wants to study abstract algebra seriously.

Comment: I was just going to say the same thing.  I wouldn't change anything about my education from D&F (except for one particularly nasty typo that was fixed several editions ago).

Comment: It's a great text book. I would recommend Herstein only for the group theory part, and Dummit and Foote for "all other parts", including ring theory, and Field theory.

Comment: I think D&F is an especially good choice if you want lots of interesting examples. It also has a huge number of good exercises. The only downsides: I find the exposition itself a bit dull, and if you read it linearly, it can take a long time to get very far, in part *because* of all the interesting and nontrivial examples which can take a fair amount of time to digest. Agree with @voldemort regarding Herstein's beautiful treatment of group theory.

Comment: I highly recommend D&F as well, but you have to be prepared to put in the time. It asks a higher level of commitment and thought than the others do, in my opinion. It doesn't spend as much time as, say, Fraleigh developing basic concepts. But the examples are outstanding, and the exercises both challenging and enlightening. The other big advantage of D&F is that it is much more than an introductory text; it will serve you well into graduate school.

Comment: I thought it was really intuitive, especially in how it used examples and exercises. It certainly assumes a certain level of aptitude and experience with abstract thought significantly beyond some introductions, but this is what allows it to be as comprehensive and intuitive as it is, and there is no significant knowledge needed as a prereq. The only reason I can see for using a different introduction is if you don't intend to go very far in abstract algebra, and so D&F is too intense. However, if you intend to go far enough to do anything in Galois Theory, I think you would benefit from D&F.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the primary disadvantages of Dummit and Foote's abstract algebra text (3rd ed.)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268887/what-are-the-primary-disadvantages-of-dummit-and-footes-abstract-algebra-text)

Answer (score 3):

I would absolutely recommend Artin's *Algebra* in your situation. Apart from the book being excellently written, one of its major advantages is that it develops linear algebra and abstract algebra in parallel. Many of the most interesting applications of groups are to geometric problems, and Artin's book is great for that.

Many other books on abstract algebra, including Dummit and Foote, have much less discussion of linear algebra. The reason for this is probably that this fits the division of university courses in the U.S. between linear algebra, taken by a wide range of students, and abstract algebra, of interest to a more restricted audience. This isn't sensible from a mathematical viewpoint.